# I’m facing a issue while using Kali on Virtual Box

Tags: kali-linux

I'm facing an issue while using Kali on Virtual Box my WiFi adapter is not showing any visible network right there in the Linux but it's visible outside my VirtualBox.

If anyone knows how to overcome that so please write the solution down here:

Here is the screenshot for what is happening with my virtual network:

[image]

Comment: Any user of Kali Linux is expected to have a solid knowledge of Linux and, in a VM, also basic notions of virtualization. It seems you need to work on both. For your specific question I hope you understand this basic stuff with the answer that has been just posted.

Comment: If anyone knows how to overcome that so please write the solution down here:    ....   I posted a working solution for you @Sahil_v3  ....  You may wish to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Most Virtual Apps, VBOX included, do not pass Network Hardware through to the guest.

Further you need wireless in Kali, normally supporting promiscuous mode to run the penetration apps.

Solution:   Get a USB Wireless Card (Panda is good) that supports promiscuous mode. Panda PAU08 does not require installation in Kali 2023.3 and above.

Then in the VBOX menu, enable USB Pass Through and pass the USB card through to the guest.  VBOX support USB pass through.

I use the above (VMware), have tested this, and am posting this from Kali 2024.1.

[image: Panda NIC in Kali]