# How do I get my Kali Linux VM to connect to the internet?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, kali-linux, vmware-workstation

I have downloaded Kali Linux on VMware and when it is in either, host only or NAT, it refuses to connect to the internet.

When I do `ifconfig` it doesn't come up with a IP address however when it is a bridged connection it would connect.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Host only will not connect to Internet  ("Host ONLY").  NAT should connect - I have Kali here connecting to Internet via NAT.   Try repairing the VMware Network Connection. Virtual Network Editor)

Comment: Kali is a pretty advanced product and is not recommended for people unfamiliar with Linux in general. Have you worked with other Linux flavors? What have you tried? What steps have you taken to connect you VM to the network or internet?

Comment: Are you the [same person who posted this](https://superuser.com/q/1835603/167207)? It is about networking issue while attempting to run Kali Linux on Virtual Box, but it is very similar. Also, please read this Unix and Linux SE post: “[Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/308480)”

Comment: I have had Kali running on VMware Workstation Pro for years. OP Post says VMware

Comment: Also make sure you are not trying to connect your host wireless directly to Kali (or any VM) Won't work.